# How to get the current cursor position in file?

Tags: file, rust

Given this code:

```
let any_offset: u64 = 42;
let mut file = File::open("/home/user/file").unwrap();
file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(any_offset));
// println!("{:?}", file.cursor_position())
```

How can I obtain the current cursor position?

Comment: inspecting the result of `seek`. See the [docs for seek](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek), `seek` returns a `Result<u64>`, where the u64 is the new position

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: Shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: It turns out that if I need it value later, then I should store it somehow, and manually update after each `seek` ? In my opinion it's stupid.

Comment: Or as alternative way: wrap File struct to my own and add needed functionality (i.e. create Proxy with position() method). But why I should do that, if it is the responsibility of File?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should call [`Seek:seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) with a relative offset of 0.  This has no side effect and returns the information you are looking for.

`Seek` is implemented for a number of types, including:

- `impl Seek for File`
- `impl<'_> Seek for &'_ File`
- `impl<'_, S: Seek + ?Sized> Seek for &'_ mut S`
- `impl<R: Seek> Seek for BufReader<R>`
- `impl<S: Seek + ?Sized> Seek for Box<S>`
- `impl<T> Seek for Cursor<T> where`
- `impl<W: Write + Seek> Seek for BufWriter<W>`

Using the [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) class [mentioned by Aaronepower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34888248/155423) might be more efficient though, since you could avoid having to make an extra system call.

Comment: So for a stream implementing `Seek` but not providing direct cursor access, the only way is `stream.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0)).unwrap()`. That's...verbose.

Comment: ...actually, there's a deeper problem: this requires mutably borrowing the stream.

Comment: Careful, if you're using a `BufWriter` this has the side affect of flushing to disk, even if the offset is just `0` like in this case. This can have a serious performance impact.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.seek) trait API the new position is returned with the seek function. However you can also take the data of the `File`, and place it within a `Vec`, and then wrap the `Vec` in a [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) which does contain a method which gets the current position.

#### Without Cursor

```
let any_offset: u64 = 42;
let mut file = File::open("/home/user/file").unwrap();
let new_position = file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(any_offset)).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", new_position);
```

#### With Cursor

```
use std::io::Cursor;

let any_offset: u64 = 42;
let mut file = File::open("/home/user/file").unwrap();
let contents = Vec::new();
file.read_to_end(&mut contents);
let mut cursor = Cursor::new(contents);
cursor.seek(SeekFrom::Start(any_offset));
println!("{:?}", cursor.position());
```

Comment: @AndreyT Updated Cursor example

Comment: Result is always = 0

Comment: You access the underlying file (`.get_ref()`), so you circumvent the cursor entirely. Result should be `0` given that. `Cursor` is not used with `File`, it's used for wrapping slices, vectors, and other in-memory data structures.

Answer (score 3):

As of Rust 1.51.0 (2021) there is now the method [`stream_position()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.stream_position) on the `Seek` trait.

```rust
use std::io::Seek;

let pos = file.stream_position().unwrap();
```

However, looking at the source code in the linked documentation this is purely a convenience wrapper that uses the same `SeekFrom::Current(0)` implementation behind the scenes.