# How can I get the current position in a `BufReader` for a file?

Tags: file, rust, io, seek

How do I get the current position of the cursor in an opened filestream in rust, after reading several lines?

For examples:
Here I am moving the cursor 6 bytes from start. Read until 50 characters. After this I would like to get the current position of the cursor, and seek the cursor again from its position.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead, SeekFrom};
use std::io::Seek;
use std::env;

fn main() {

    let fafile: String = "temp.fa".to_string();
    let mut file = File::open(fafile).expect("Nope!");
    let seekto: u64 = 6;
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(seekto)); //open a file and seek 6 bytes
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let mut text: String = "".to_string();

    //Stop reading after 50 characters
    for line in reader.lines(){
        let line = line.unwrap();
        text.push_str(&line);
        if text.len() > 50{ 
            break;
        }
    }

   //How do I get the current position of the cursor? and
  // Can I seek again to a new position without reopening the file? 
  //I have tried below but it doesnt work.

   //file.seek(SeekFrom::Current(6)); 

}
```

I have checked [seek](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) which offers to move the cursor from `start`, `end` and `current` but does not tell me the current position.

Comment: Not really. As one of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878970/how-to-get-current-cursor-position-in-file#comment95244996_34889413) pointed, there is this issue with `moved value` which makes `file` no longer accessible after first seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question, [`seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) returns the new position after moving. So you can get the current position by seeking with an offset of 0 from the current:

```
let current_pos = reader.seek (SeekFrom::Current (0)).expect ("Could not get current position!");
```

(see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878970/how-to-get-current-cursor-position-in-file))

Regarding the second question, you can no longer access the `file` variable once you've moved it into the `BufReader`, but you can call seek on the reader itself:

```
reader.seek (SeekFrom::Current (6)).expect ("Seek failed!");
```

As pointed out in the comments, this only works if you haven't moved the reader, so you also need to change your reading loop to borrow `reader` instead of moving it:

```
for line in reader.by_ref().lines() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, its the same issue with `reader` variable as well. I  get the same error as `value moved`. I know exact position of the strings that I want in a large text file. I need to seek from one position after another without re-opening the file for faster random access.

Comment: it's not the same issue: now your reader is being consumed by the `lines()` call. You can use `reader.by_ref().lines()` to avoid moving reader.

Comment: Great. This works.